# Styling background image into table header with css

Tags: html, css

I've got a grid that I am generating on a webpage, with a some styling attached to it. The header has a background image applied to it. When the header is ONE line deep, it looks fine. The second that the header spans two lines (with a line break) it looks like the attachment. I've tried fiddling with the height but I just can't get it to take.

```
    <style>
.Grid {background-color: #fff; margin: 5px 0 10px 0; border: solid 1px #525252; border-collapse:collapse; font-family:Calibri; color: #474747;}
.Grid td {
      padding: 2px;
      border: solid 1px #c1c1c1; }
.Grid th  {
      padding : 4px 2px;
      color: #000000;
      background: #363670 url(images/grid-header.png) repeat-x top;
      border-left: solid 1px #525252;
      font-size: 0.9em;
      }
.Grid .alt {
      background: #fcfcfc url(images/grid-alt.png) repeat-x top; }
.Grid .pgr {background: #363670 url(images/grid-pgr.png) repeat-x top; }
.Grid .pgr table { margin: 3px 0; }
.Grid .pgr td { border-width: 0; padding: 0 6px; border-left: solid 1px #666; font-weight: bold; color: #fff; line-height: 12px; }  
.Grid .pgr a { color: Gray; text-decoration: none; }
.Grid .pgr a:hover { color: #000; text-decoration: none; }

</style>
```

[image]

Comment: What is the desired outcome? For the image to stretch to the height?

Comment: Yeah, if you look at the screenshot, that line in the middle is where the image at its natural height (above) ends, and the background color of the th cell begins. I just want that upper part to stretch to 100% of the height. The repeat-x I think takes care of the width, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the `.Grid th` try adding

```
background-size: auto 100%;
```

The first variable is width, which we want whatever the normal behavior is because it's already working, and the second is height and is saying use 100% of available height.

Comment: exactly what I needed. Thanks!